# slideDown and slideUp multiple fields with jQuery

Tags: jquery, slide, slidedown, slideup, toggleclass

I'm trying to slide multiple contents down with show fields. This works fine. Also the class changes nicely to "up". Yet, when I click the text again, nothing happens.
Why doesn't this work? Does anyone have a better solution?

```
jQuery('#slidetoggle.down').click(function(e){
    jQuery('.slider').slideUp();
    jQuery(this).text('show fields');
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('down');
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('up');
});
jQuery('#slidetoggle.up').click(function(e){
    jQuery('.slider').slideDown();
    jQuery(this).text('hide fields');
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('up');
    jQuery(this).toggleClass('down');
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Code like:

```
jQuery('some selector')
```

says to find elements that match `'some selector'` *right now,* not keep an eye out for elements that might match the selector at some later point.

Presumably your element only has one of the 'up' and 'down' classes initially, so only one of the click handlers is bound.

You could do this instead:

```
jQuery('#slidetoggle').click(function(e){
    if ($(this).hasClass('down')) {
       jQuery('.slider').slideUp();
       jQuery(this).text('show fields').toggleClass('down up');
    } else {
       jQuery('.slider').slideDown();
       jQuery(this).text('hide fields').toggleClass('up down');
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/SBDDx/

Answer (score 0):

If i am geeting you correctly then you also need to change the ID because I suppose that you are using the same button .. You are changing the text but not the id of the input ...so the code for the other ID will not work

Neverthless you need to write this code for one selector something like this

```
jQuery('#slidetoggle').click(function(e)
{
  var text   = (jQuery(this).text() == 'show fields')?'hide field':'show fields';
  jQuery('.slider').slideToggle();
  jQuery(this).text(text);
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('down');
  jQuery(this).toggleClass('up');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the `.up` elements do not exist on page load.

You should do it "slightly" different :)

```
$('#slidetoggle')
.on('click', function(e){
    var $this = $(this),
        $slider = $('.slider'),
        isOpened = $slider.is(':visible');

    if (isOpened)
    {
        $slider.slideUp();
        $this.text('show fields');
    }
    else
    {
        $slider.slideDown();
        $this.text('hide fields');
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qwL33/

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is toggle-

```
jQuery('#slidetoggle').click(function(e){
   jQuery('.slider').toggle('slideUp');
```

});

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Eeq3u/)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the same result with a different strategy.

Initially hide one of the buttons with display:none;. 
Then:

```
jQuery('#slidetoggle.down').click(function(e){
    jQuery('.slider').slideUp();
    jQuery(this).hide();
    jQuery('#slidetoggle.up').show();
});
jQuery('#slidetoggle.up').click(function(e){
    jQuery('.slider').slideDown();
    jQuery(this).hide();
    jQuery('#slidetoggle.down').show();
});
```